# Как можно запретить ввод текста внутри виджета?

Tags: виджет, ckeditor

Несмотря на параметр allowedContent, виджет всё равно позволяет вводить текст. Как запретить прямой ввод с клавиатуры?

Comment: Ам, а можно пример?

Comment: Прошу прощения, пример чего?

Comment: @heleg Пример виджета